# Smartface Download Freezes

Tags: smartface.io

When I try to install Smartface.io the installer freezes completely when it reaches about 160 MB of 172 MB.
I've checked the boxes for the .NET Framework, iTunes, JDK 1.7, Android SDK and Node.js. It also starts with SmartfaceAppStudio.exe already checked.

I have tested with both Windows 10 and 7, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Does it give any error? If yes, can you please share the error.

Comment: no any errors, but the problem is the download bar suddenly freezes and stops , and the program installation window all stops and also the buttons of cancel, pause and back also not working or unpressible

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved

i installed hotspot shield and connected with a United States IP

and the download completed without any problems